# Count number of days passed over the last year until a limit from multiple date intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, intervals

I want to be able to count the number of days that have passed in the last year (arbitrarily set) based on multiple date intervals within a group. When 100 days have been counted, I would like it to stop counting, and then start again when the last year (365 or 366 days) have not had 100 days counted.

Example sample data (Sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/SPVZol7L):

| Group | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 |
| 2 | 01-02-2020 | 01-03-2020 |
| 2 | 01-09-2020 | 01-12-2020 |

For the first group there's been 100 days between 01-01-2020 and 09-04-2020. I would like to stop counting after that and start again on the 02-01-2021 from the next interval, where the last year (366 days, leap year) have not had 100 days counted.

I've tried cross joining a dimensional table containing all dates so I can easily count consecutive number of days also across multiple date intervals as shown above. But I do not know how to look back at the last 365 days and see, if 100 days have already been counted. It would be nice if I could output number of days counted next to each interval, or prefereably each month that has passed within each interval. Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Expected result could look like this:

| Group | StartDate | EndDate | YearMonth | CountDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202001 | 31 |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202002 | 29 |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202003 | 31 |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202004 | 9 |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202005 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202006 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 01-07-2020 | 202007 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202008 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202009 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202010 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202011 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202012 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202101 | 30 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202102 | 28 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202103 | 31 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202104 | 11 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202105 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202106 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-08-2020 | 01-07-2021 | 202107 | 0 |
| 2 | 01-02-2020 | 01-03-2020 | 202002 | 29 |
| 2 | 01-02-2020 | 01-03-2020 | 202003 | 1 |
| 2 | 01-09-2020 | 01-12-2020 | 202009 | 30 |
| 2 | 01-09-2020 | 01-12-2020 | 202010 | 31 |
| 2 | 01-09-2020 | 01-12-2020 | 202011 | 9 |
| 2 | 01-09-2020 | 01-12-2020 | 202012 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET dateformat dmy;

CREATE TABLE SampleData (
   [Group] Varchar(20),
   [StartDate] Date,
   [EndDate] Date
);

INSERT INTO SampleData ([Group], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES ('1', '01-01-2020', '01-07-2020'), 
       ('1', '01-08-2020', '01-07-2021'), 
       ('2', '01-02-2020', '01-03-2020'), 
       ('2', '01-09-2020', '01-12-2020');

SELECT * FROM SampleData
```

| Group | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-07-01 |
| 1 | 2020-08-01 | 2021-07-01 |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-12-01 |

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = (SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM SampleData)
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM SampleData)

;WITH n AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 
    FROM n 
    WHERE n + 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate)
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @MinDate) AS Date 
INTO #Calendar
FROM n 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

CREATE TABLE #Result
(
    Date DATE,
    [Group] VARCHAR(20),
    Counted INT,
    CumulativeCount INT,
    ResetDate DATE
)

DECLARE @Group VARCHAR(20), @Date DATE

DECLARE GroupCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT [Group] FROM SampleData
OPEN GroupCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM GroupCursor INTO @Group

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE DateCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Date FROM #Calendar ORDER BY Date
    OPEN DateCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM DateCursor INTO @Date

    DECLARE @CumulativeCount INT = 0, @ResetDate DATE = NULL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Counted INT = 
        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM SampleData
            WHERE [Group] = @Group AND @Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        )

        IF @Counted = 1 AND (@CumulativeCount = 0 OR DATEDIFF(DAY, @ResetDate, @Date) > 365) 
        BEGIN
            SET @CumulativeCount = 1
            SET @ResetDate = @Date
        END
        ELSE IF @Counted = 1 AND @CumulativeCount < 100
            SET @CumulativeCount = @CumulativeCount + 1
        ELSE IF @Counted = 1 AND @CumulativeCount >= 100
            SET @Counted = 0

        INSERT INTO #Result (Date, [Group], Counted, CumulativeCount, ResetDate)
        VALUES (@Date, @Group, @Counted, @CumulativeCount, @ResetDate)

        FETCH NEXT FROM DateCursor INTO @Date
    END
    CLOSE DateCursor
    DEALLOCATE DateCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM GroupCursor INTO @Group
END
CLOSE GroupCursor
DEALLOCATE GroupCursor

SELECT 
    [Group],
    FORMAT(Date, 'yyyyMM') AS YearMonth,
    SUM(Counted) AS CountDays
FROM #Result
GROUP BY [Group], FORMAT(Date, 'yyyyMM')
ORDER BY [Group], YearMonth
```

| Group | YearMonth | CountDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202001 | 31 |
| 1 | 202002 | 29 |
| 1 | 202003 | 31 |
| 1 | 202004 | 9 |
| 1 | 202005 | 0 |
| 1 | 202006 | 0 |
| 1 | 202007 | 0 |
| 1 | 202008 | 0 |
| 1 | 202009 | 0 |
| 1 | 202010 | 0 |
| 1 | 202011 | 0 |
| 1 | 202012 | 0 |
| 1 | 202101 | 31 |
| 1 | 202102 | 28 |
| 1 | 202103 | 31 |
| 1 | 202104 | 10 |
| 1 | 202105 | 0 |
| 1 | 202106 | 0 |
| 1 | 202107 | 0 |
| 2 | 202001 | 0 |
| 2 | 202002 | 29 |
| 2 | 202003 | 1 |
| 2 | 202004 | 0 |
| 2 | 202005 | 0 |
| 2 | 202006 | 0 |
| 2 | 202007 | 0 |
| 2 | 202008 | 0 |
| 2 | 202009 | 30 |
| 2 | 202010 | 31 |
| 2 | 202011 | 9 |
| 2 | 202012 | 0 |
| 2 | 202101 | 0 |
| 2 | 202102 | 0 |
| 2 | 202103 | 0 |
| 2 | 202104 | 0 |
| 2 | 202105 | 0 |
| 2 | 202106 | 0 |
| 2 | 202107 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5JZBnDVE)