# Counting days cummulatively over the last year over multiple date intervals within groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, intervals

This is a continuation of a previous question. After having resolved my initial question [(Previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76752045/count-number-of-days-passed-over-the-last-year-until-a-limit-from-multiple-date/76752771?noredirect=1#comment135356115_76752771), I realized that I needed to add some complexity to my question to properly solve my usecase.

I need to calculate the first 100 days of a year within groups which contains multiple date intervals. The start of the year is set arbitrarily from the first date of the first interval within each group. I also need to be able to output two variables [Location] and [Amount] associated with each interval. My problem is then that some of these intervals will overlap with a single day (identical EndDate and following StartDate), which messes up my count.

I have the following sample data [Fiddle for sample data and code attempt](https://dbfiddle.uk/xYmJpjl3)

| Group | Location | Amount | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Location1 | 100 | 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150 | 2021-02-01 | 2022-07-01 |
| 2 | Location3 | 200 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2 | Location1 | 100 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-12-01 |

It would like the following output:

| Group | Location | Amount | YearMonth | CountDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202001 | 31 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202002 | 29 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202003 | 31 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202004 | 9 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202005 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202006 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202007 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202008 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202009 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202010 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202011 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202012 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202101 | 31 |
| 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202102 | 1 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202102 | 28 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202103 | 31 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202104 | 9 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202105 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202106 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202107 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202108 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202109 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202110 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202111 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202112 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202201 | 31 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202202 | 28 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202203 | 31 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202204 | 10 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202205 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202206 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 202207 | 0 |
| 2 | Location3 | 200.00 | 202002 | 29 |
| 2 | Location3 | 200.00 | 202003 | 1 |
| 2 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202009 | 30 |
| 2 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202010 | 31 |
| 2 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202011 | 9 |
| 2 | Location1 | 100.00 | 202012 | 0 |

I tried using the following (rewritten from previous question):

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = (SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM SampleData)
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = (SELECT MAX(EndDate) FROM SampleData)

;WITH n AS 
(
    SELECT 0 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 
    FROM n 
    WHERE n + 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate)
)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, @MinDate) AS Date
INTO #Calendar
FROM n 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

  
CREATE TABLE #Result
(
    Date DATE,
    [Group] VARCHAR(20),
    [Location] VARCHAR(100),
    [Amount] DECIMAL(10,2),
    Counted INT,
    CumulativeCount INT,
    ResetDate DATE
);

DECLARE @Group VARCHAR(20), @Date DATE, @Location VARCHAR(100), @Amount DECIMAL(10,2);

DECLARE GroupCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT [Group], [Location], [Amount] FROM SampleData
OPEN GroupCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM GroupCursor INTO @Group, @Location, @Amount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE DateCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Date FROM #Calendar ORDER BY Date
    OPEN DateCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM DateCursor INTO @Date

    DECLARE @CumulativeCount INT = 0, @ResetDate DATE = NULL
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @Counted INT = 
        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            FROM SampleData
            WHERE [Group] = @Group AND @Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        )

            IF @Counted = 1 AND (@CumulativeCount = 0 OR DATEDIFF(DAY, @ResetDate, @Date) >= DATEDIFF(DAY, @ResetDate, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @ResetDate))) --- Altered check to account for leap years. 
                BEGIN
                    SET @CumulativeCount = 1
                    SET @ResetDate = @Date  
                END
            ELSE IF @Counted = 1 AND @CumulativeCount < 100 
                SET @CumulativeCount = @CumulativeCount + 1
            ELSE IF @Counted = 1 AND @CumulativeCount >= 100
                SET @Counted = 0
        

        IF  
        ( 
            SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
              FROM SampleData
              WHERE [Group] = @Group AND [Location] = @Location AND [Amount] = @Amount AND @Date BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        ) = 1
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Result (Date, [Group], [Location], [Amount], Counted, CumulativeCount, ResetDate)
                VALUES (@Date, @Group, @Location, @Amount, @Counted, @CumulativeCount, @ResetDate)
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM DateCursor INTO @Date
    END
    CLOSE DateCursor
    DEALLOCATE DateCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM GroupCursor INTO @Group, @Location, @Amount

END
CLOSE GroupCursor
DEALLOCATE GroupCursor

SELECT * FROM #Result
ORDER BY [Group], Date

SELECT 
    [Group],
    [Location],
    [Amount],
    FORMAT(Date, 'yyyyMM') AS YearMonth,
    SUM(Counted) AS CountDays
FROM #Result
GROUP BY [Group], [Location], [Amount], FORMAT(Date, 'yyyyMM')
ORDER BY [Group], YearMonth, [Location]
```

This does nearly exactly what I need, but I have a problem with the duplicate dates (example of 2021-02-01). Here, the variable @CumulativeCount does not update properly across the duplicate dates - which leads to counting more than 100 days in the end. I have tried multiple workarounds and fixes but have so far come up with no solution that fixes it (and doesnt break anything).

Here's a snippet of the #Results to show the problem:

| Date | Group | Location | Amount | Counted | CumulativeCount | ResetDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-31 | 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 1 | 31 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1 | Location1 | 100.00 | 1 | 32 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-02-01 | 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 1 | 32 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2021-02-02 | 1 | Location2 | 150.00 | 1 | 33 | 2021-01-01 |

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can't you just adjust the in-data by removing one day from EndDate if it matches StartDate of next "row"

Comment: Unfortunately not, both dates are "valid" and need to be counted.

Comment: Add 1 day to the end date, and _DateDiff_ will count the days correctly, including leap years. Then split that count of days into up to three full months and leave the remaining count of days to reach 100 in  the last (<=fourth) month.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks for the comment. I am not sure I follow this suggestion. Would you be able to show me in code what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do that much T-SQL. But Patrick is on the right track. If you have _Microsoft Access_, you can study the demo at my *GitHub* repository [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date) holding the query _DaysInMonthsOfDateRanges_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for cursors if you take advantage of analytic functions to compute the cumulative days numbers.

My query uses a SQL Server 2022 function to explode the dates into a series of  months via `cross apply` and `generate_series()`. You can replace that with whatever method you prefer. It also uses `date_bucket()` to compute a relative reference date for each logical year. Substitute an equivalent calculation if necessary. The rest is just a straightforward summation followed by some `case` logic to cap at 100 days.

```
with explode as (
    select *,
        date_bucket(year, 1, Mnth,
            min(StartDate) over (partition by [Group])) as ReferenceDate,
        case when Mnth <> eomonth(EndDate) then day(Mnth) else 1 end as Counter
    from SampleData data cross apply (
        select eomonth(dateadd(month, value, StartDate)) as Mnth
        from generate_series(0, 99) -- adjust if 100 months isn't enough...
        where dateadd(month, value, StartDate) <= EndDate
    ) months
), accumulate as (
    select *,
        sum(Counter) over (partition by [Group], ReferenceDate order by Mnth) as CumDays
    from explode
)
select [Group], Location, Amount,
    convert(char(6), Mnth, 112) as YearMonth,
    case when CumDays <= 100 then Counter
         when CumDays - Counter < 100 then 100 - (CumDays - Counter)
         else 0 end as CountDays
from accumulate
order by [Group], YearMonth, Location;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ZSYJpC5A

Comment: Does exactly what I asked for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're going to want to employ a calendar table, and then use it something like this:

```
SELECT t.GroupID, t.Location, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, c.Year, c.Month, COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,(DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,t.StartDate,c.Date),t.StartDate)),c.Date) < 100 THEN 1 END) AS CountDays
  FROM @Table t
    INNER JOIN dbo.Calendar(3,1) c
      ON t.StartDate <= c.Date
      AND t.EndDate >= c.Date
 GROUP BY t.GroupID, t.Location, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, c.Year, c.Month
 ORDER BY GroupID, Location, c.Year, c.Month
```

| GroupID | Location | StartDate | EndDate | Year | Month | CountDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 1 | 31 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 2 | 29 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 3 | 31 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 4 | 9 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 9 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 11 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 1 | 31 |
| 1 | Location1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 2 | 28 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 3 | 31 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 4 | 30 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 5 | 11 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 8 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 9 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 10 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 11 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 1 | 31 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 2 | 28 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 3 | 31 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 4 | 30 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 5 | 11 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | Location2 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | Location1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 9 | 30 |
| 2 | Location1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 10 | 31 |
| 2 | Location1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 11 | 30 |
| 2 | Location1 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | Location3 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 2 | 29 |
| 2 | Location3 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020 | 3 | 1 |

If you can't/don't want to implement a calendar table or function, you could build a pseudo version using a `CTE`:

```
;WITH CalendarCTE AS (
SELECT MIN(StartDate) AS Date, MAX(EndDate) AS mxDate, DATEPART(MONTH,MIN(StartDate)) AS Month, DATEPART(YEAR,MIN(StartDate)) AS Year
FROM @Table
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,Date), mxDate, DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) AS Month, DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,1,Date)) AS Year
  FROM CalendarCTE
 WHERE Date < mxDate
)

SELECT t.GroupID, t.Location, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, c.Year, c.Month, COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,(DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,t.StartDate,c.Date),t.StartDate)),c.Date) < 100 THEN 1 END) AS CountDays
  FROM @Table t
    INNER JOIN CalendarCTE c
      ON t.StartDate <= c.Date
      AND t.EndDate >= c.Date
 GROUP BY t.GroupID, t.Location, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, c.Year, c.Month
 ORDER BY GroupID, Location, c.Year, c.Month
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. This does not however solve my problem, because it seems to reset the count to 100 whenever a new interval is consideret - I need it to count across intervals within the Group ID's. Also, it for some reason counts to 131 between months 1-5 of year 2022 for Group = 1, which I do not understand. I'll have a look though to see if I can adjust it for my usecase.